# How to check ARGF is empty or not in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to do with `ARGF` like this.

```
# file.rb
if ARGF.???
  puts ARGF.read
else
  puts "no redirect."
end

$ echo "Hello world" | ruby file.rb
Hello world

$ ruby file.rb
no redirect.
```

I need to do without waiting user input. I tried `eof?` or `closed?` doesn't help. Any ideas?

**NOTE** I was misunderstood `ARGF`. please see comments below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you'd examine `#filename`. One way to do this is:

```
if ARGF.filename != "-"
  puts ARGF.read
else
  puts "no redirect."
end
```

And this is the more complete form:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
if ARGF.filename != "-" or (not STDIN.tty? and not STDIN.closed?)
  puts ARGF.read
else
  puts "No redirect."
end
```

Another:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
if not STDIN.tty? and not STDIN.closed?
  puts STDIN.read
else
  puts "No redirect."
end
```

Comment: `echo "Hello World" | ruby file.rb` will return `filename` `-`

Comment: @fl00r Besides checking for ARGF, you'd also need to check if stdin is a terminal input or not. See update.

Comment: 2nd sample worked for me. but `$ ruby file.rb foo` returns
      `file.rb:2:in filename': No such file or directory - foo (Errno::ENOENT)
      from file.rb:2:in <main>'`
Can I avoid this error?

Comment: Does `foo` really exist? Do you also want to check if it exists and avoid reading if not?

Comment: @MarcJ You probably have to clear any non-existing files from ARGV yourselves. It seems `filename` only gives the name of the first file, so it fairly useless to use if input is `ruby file.rb existing.txt non-existing.txt`. You can do something like `ARGV.select! { |file| File.exists?(file) }` before you use `ARGF` and have processed other parameters to only leave parameters that point to existing files.

Comment: `foo` I said was just an example. `$ ruby file.rb file.rb` returns entire file. How could you make always 'No redirect' at both ways?

Comment: @MarcJ If you don't need to process file arguments, you just have to completely avoid ARGF and use STDIN instead. Please see update.

Comment: The third one returns `false` if ARGF is passed as ARGV[0]

Answer (score 1):

There might be a better way, but for me I needed to read the contents of a files being passed as arguments as well as having a files contents redirected to stdin.

my_executable

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts ARGF.pos.zero?
```

Then

```
$ my_executable file1.txt   # passed as argument
#=> true
$ my_executable < file1.txt # redirected to stdin
#=> true
$ my_executable
#=> false
```

Comment: `$ echo "123" | ruby -e "p ARGF.pos"` -> `-e:1:in 'pos': Illegal seek @ rb_io_tell - <STDIN> (Errno::ESPIPE)`

Answer (score 0):

So I took all three currently suggested solutions:

```rb
p (not STDIN.tty? and not STDIN.closed?)
p ARGF.filename
p ARGF.pos
```

and saw that none of them actually works:

```
$ ruby temp.rb 
false
"-"
36471287

$ ruby temp.rb temp.rb 
false
"temp.rb"
0

$ echo 123 | ruby temp.rb 
true
"-"
temp.rb:3:in `pos': Illegal seek @ rb_io_tell - <STDIN> (Errno::ESPIPE)
        from temp.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

because to assume the ability to call the `ARGF.read` you want to get false/true/true.

So I suppose you have to combine them:

```rb
!STDIN.tty? && !STDIN.closed? || ARGF.filename != ?-
```